# Cohesive way to validate a class in Scala using Scalaz 7

Tags: validation, scala, single-responsibility-principle, scalaz7

My goal is to validate `User`'s fields within the `object`'s `apply`method before creating one effective `User` instance:

```
case class User(String userName, String password)

object User {

  def apply(userValidator: UserValidator): ValidationNel[UserCreationFailure, User] = {
    //call UserValidator's validate() method here and initialize effective User instance.
  }

}
```

I chose to use `Validation` from **Scalaz7** to accumulate potential illegal arguments / errors.

One drawback in the following code is that Scalaz7 API force me to make the validator creates itself the instance. However, by following **Single-Responsibility principle**, it's clearly not its role. Its role would be to just validate fields and to return some errors list.

Let's first present my actual code (for information, `Empty****` objects are just some `case object` extending `UserCreationFailure`):

```
class UserValidator(val userName: String, val password: String)
  extends CommonValidator[UserCreationFailure] {

  def validate(): ValidationNel[UserCreationFailure, User] = {
    (checkForUserName ⊛
      checkForPassword)((userName, password) => new User(userName, password)
  }

  private def checkForUserName: ValidationNel[UserCreationFailure, String] = {
    checkForNonEmptyString(userName) {
      EmptyUserName
    }
  }

  def checkForPassword: ValidationNel[UserCreationFailure, String] = {
    checkForNonEmptyString(password) {
      EmptyPassword
    }
  }
}
```

What I would expect is to merely return this snippet code:

```
(checkForUserName ⊛ checkForPassword)
```

and bring the appropriate result into my `User` class, allowing to create the effective instance by doing:

```
def apply(userValidator: UserValidator): ValidationNel[UserCreationFailure, User] = {
        userValidator(username, password).validate()((userName, password)(new User(userName, password))
 }
```

Indeed, it would be more friendly with SRP.

But `(checkForUserName ⊛ checkForPassword)` returns a totally `private` type type:

`private[scalaz] trait ApplicativeBuilder[M[_], A, B]`,

thus I don't have the hand on the type of `class` returned.

Therefore, I am forced to directly associate User's creation with it.

How could I keep SRP and keep this validation mechanism?

**-----UPDATE**----

As @Travis Brown mentioned, the intent to use an external `class` for my `UserValidator` may seem weird. Actually, I expect the validator to be mockable and thus, I'm forced to use composition over `trait`/`abstract class`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand why you need a dedicated `UserValidator` class in the first place. In a case like this I'd be more likely to bundle all of my generic validation code into a separate trait, and to have my `User` companion object (or whatever other piece I want to be responsible for creating `User` instances) extend that trait. Here's a quick sketch:

```
import scalaz._, Scalaz._

trait Validator[E] {
  def checkNonEmpty(error: E)(s: String): ValidationNel[E, String] =
    if (s.isEmpty) error.failNel else s.successNel
}

sealed trait UserCreationFailure
case object EmptyPassword extends UserCreationFailure
case object EmptyUsername extends UserCreationFailure

case class User(name: String, pass: String)

object User extends Validator[UserCreationFailure] {
  def validated(
    name: String,
    pass: String
  ): ValidationNel[UserCreationFailure, User] = (
    checkNonEmpty(EmptyUsername)(name) |@| checkNonEmpty(EmptyPassword)(pass)
  )(apply)
}
```

And then:

```
scala> println(User.validated("", ""))
Failure(NonEmptyList(EmptyUsername, EmptyPassword))

scala> println(User.validated("a", ""))
Failure(NonEmptyList(EmptyPassword))

scala> println(User.validated("", "b"))
Failure(NonEmptyList(EmptyUsername))

scala> println(User.validated("a", "b"))
Success(User(a,b))
```

If you have a huge amount of `User`-specific validation logic that you don't want polluting your `User` object, I suppose you could factor it out into a `UserValidator` trait that would extend your generic `Validator` and be extended by `User`.

Comment: Why I want to deal with composition instead of trait(inheritance) is because I expect my `UserValidator`to be mockable. The entire objective is to provide a `mockable` `UserValidator` in order to fit my unit tests regarding `User` class.

Comment: And of course, we can't mock any trait/superclass of one precised class.

Comment: I like your solution despite I think to keep composition, thus with an  external `UserValidator` class, but letting `User` class make the appropriate different validation method calls, as you has presented.   Thanks a lot :)